# Возможно ли в linux получить данные от DDE сервера в Windows?

Tags: linux, windows

Или проще написать на Windows DDE клиент и по сокету все передавать в другую систему? (как пример)

Comment: [java dde](http://jdde.pretty-tools.com/), но с большой вероятностью не будет работать даже в *ms/windows*, не говоря уж про что-то другое.